# Python post request returns url instead of base64 string

Tags: python, post, python-requests, base64

I am calling an API that requires a post request to be made to generate a data download report as either a base64 encoded string or a file in the frontend website.
My current code generates the response of type requests.model.Response. When I coerce to JSON, the output is :

```
  {'errorMessage': '', 
'fileName': 'Reports\\test_2.csv', 
'file': '', 
'URI': 'HTTPS://C31.IT.COM/API/services/V167.0/files?fileName=Reports%5ctest_2.csv'}
```

No base64 string is generated and nor is there a file generated in the website. How do I get the output? The base64 string is generated when I try it from the API site. 
My code is as follows:

```
 reportId = '350048'
fileName = 'test_2.csv'
startDate = (date.today() - timedelta(days=1)).isoformat()
endDate = (date.today()).isoformat()
saveAsFile = 'true'
includeHeaders = 'true'
BASEURL = (data["resource_server_base_uri"])
accessToken = (data["access_token"])
# =============================================================================
payload={'reportId' : reportId,
'fileName' : fileName,
'startDate' : startDate,
'endDate' : endDate,
'saveAsFile' : saveAsFile,
'includeHeaders' : includeHeaders
}
# =============================================================================
#add all necessary headers
header_param = {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + accessToken,
                 'content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                 'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*'}

# Make http post request
response_2 = requests.post(BASEURL +'/services/v17.0/report-jobs/datadownload/'+ reportId +
                                   '?startDate=' + startDate + '&endDate=' + endDate + '&saveAsFile=' + saveAsFile + '&includeHeaders=' + includeHeaders ,
                                   headers = header_param, data = payload )
```